# Ruby Terminology Question: Implicit Declaration or no declaration at all?

Tags: ruby

I have a question, because in most serious sources I read, all say the same `No variable is ever declared in Ruby`, but still I have doubts, because according to what I was taught in my university implicit declaration is when a variable is created via allocation, where you can specify the type of a variable through conventions established in the language.

This contrasts with explicit declaration, when the data type specified in its declaration, like C... or at least that's what I understood.

So I was taught wrong?, or I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What they said:

> No variable is ever declared in Ruby

What they meant:

> There is no keyword defining a line of code as declaring a variable. Variables can just be used, and at worst are `nil`.

If you have not previously assigned a value to a variable in Ruby, it becomes `nil` as soon as you retrieve its value.

```
class Foo
  def bar
    @bar
  end
end

a = Foo.new
puts a.bar
```

You weren't taught wrong. They just describe it in a non academic way.

Comment: Constant variables and class hierarchy variables raise a `NameError` if they are not defined, instance variables and global variables evaluate to `nil`, and local variables also evaluate to `nil` but need to be disambiguated from a method call by being lexically defined first, otherwise they will raise a `NameError` but for being ambiguous, not undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Different variables behave differently in Ruby, but none of them need explicit declaration.

The most interesting behavior is for local variables: Ruby allows you to leave off the receiver for a message send to `self` (`self` is the implicit receiver), so `foo()` is the same thing as `self.foo()`, and it also allows you to leave off the argument list if there are no arguments, so `foo.bar` is the same thing as `foo.bar()`; putting the two together, we get that `foo` is the same thing as `self.foo()`, i.e. a message send without arguments to the implicit receiver `self`. It could, however, also be a reference to the local variable `foo`. This ambiguity is resolved the following way: `foo` is interpreted as a message send, *unless* an assignment to `foo` has been *parsed* (but *not* necessarily *executed*) before, then from that point on it is interpreted as a local variable.

This is the closest thing Ruby has to variable declaration:

```
foo
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo'

defined?(foo)
# => nil

def foo; 23 end

foo
# => 23

defined?(foo)
# => 'method'

methods
# => [:foo, …]

if false then foo = 42 end

foo
# => nil

defined?(foo)
# => 'local-variable'

local_variables
# => [:foo]
```

Note that the `NameError` is *not* raised because the local variable is undefined, but because Ruby doesn't know what to make of the expression: is it a local variable or a method call?

Instance variables and global variables behave similarly, they evaluate to `nil` even if they are not defined:

```
@foo
# => nil

defined?(@foo)
# => nil

@foo = 42

@foo
# => 42

defined?(@foo)
# => 'instance-variable'

instance_variables
# => [:@foo]

$foo
# => nil

defined?($foo)
# => nil

$foo = 42

$foo
# => 42

defined?($foo)
# => 'global-variable'

global_variables
# => [:$foo, …]
```

Class hierarchy variables and constants behave differently, they raise `NameError` if they are not defined:

```
@@foo
# NameError

defined?(@@foo)
# => nil

@@foo = 42

@@foo
# => 42

defined?(@@foo)
# => 'class-variable'

self.class.class_variables
# => [:@@foo]

FOO
# NameError

defined?(FOO)
# => nil

FOO = 42

FOO
# => 42

defined?(FOO)
# => 'constant'

self.class.constants
# => [:FOO]
```